# rendered video is different from preview

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've been going through a video and trying to extract parts from it,rendering each part as segments. partly through I realized that the resulting files had a slightly different part than was being played in the previews. how can I make it so that the video I see and hear in the preview is the same video that gets written to the file?

Comment: probably you didn't  enable AVsync?

Comment: Have you tried rendering in OpenGL?.  That's accessed at top left of 3D window in the "Render" drop-down.  Select  "OpenGL Render Animation".  It's a WYSIWYG render. (most times)

Comment: It’s the codec. Render to still frames then cut.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Turns out that the **Proxy render size** under **View Settings**, Really destroys the accuracy of the video in preview.

Notice how the 'Text' and 'Character' deviates from its original location.

[image: Notice how the Text and Character deviates from its original location.]

Images and Videos are not affected, But  Text, Any sort of animation is affected.

The solution I found for myself is to fix all the glitches manually in **full render** settings.

**Edit:**

**Turn on AV Sync. You will find it under Timeline-> Playback -> AV Sync (check mark).**